# Swing arrow at a varying speed

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

How can I make an arrow swing like in [this video](https://streamable.com/lwp1n)?

So far, I can rotate my node back and forth like in [this video](https://streamable.com/vpm6v) using the following code in `didMove(to:)` in my `SKScene`:

```
// Ball
let ballNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball")
let offsetFromCorner: CGFloat = 20
ballNode.position = CGPoint(x: frame.minX + ballNode.size.width / 2 + offsetFromCorner, y: frame.minY + ballNode.size.height / 2 + offsetFromCorner)
addChild(ballNode)

/* ... */

// Aim arrow
let aimArrowNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "AimArrow")
aimArrowNode.position.y += aimArrowNode.size.height / 2
ballNode.addChild(aimArrowNode)
ballNode.zRotation = -.pi / 18 * 8
let rotateUp = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: -.pi / 18, duration: 1)
let rotateDown = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: -.pi / 18 * 8, duration: 1)
let combinedActions = SKAction.sequence([rotateUp, rotateDown])
ballNode.run(SKAction.repeatForever(combinedActions))
```

However, I want the arrow to appear to "slow down" as it gets nearer to the edge. How can I achieve this?

---

**If you have any questions, please ask!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, the answer is actually built into `SKAction`.

Just add these after you create the actions:

```
rotateUp.timingMode = .easeInEaseOut
rotateDown.timingMode = .easeInEaseOut
```

Now you get the effect I was looking for! :)